# Prevent vuetify checkbox from checking itself?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**I want the v-checkbox to remain unchanged after I write in the text field.**

**What is happening:**

The checkbox checks itself whenever I click outside the box or type in the text field below.

**What is expected:**

The checkbox to remain unchecked until the use checks it.

Code:

```
export default {
props: ['answer'],
data() {
    return {
        newAnswer: 'Your answer here...',
        multiChoiceAnswers: {
            answers: ['test1', 'test2'],
            selected: [],
        }
    }
},
created() {
    if (this.answer.answers.length > 1) {
        this.multiChoiceAnswers.answers = this.answer.answers
        this.multiChoiceAnswers.selected = this.answer.selected
    } else {
        console.log('Answer Template Generated')
    }
},
methods: {
    selectedAnswer(clickEvent, index) {
        console.log(clickEvent, index)
        //Checking wether or not the answer is a value or null
        //in order to push or remove it from the selected answers
        if (clickEvent === this.multiChoiceAnswers.answers[index]) {
            this.multiChoiceAnswers.selected.push(clickEvent)
        } else {
            const selectedPosition = this.multiChoiceAnswers.selected.indexOf(this.multiChoiceAnswers.answers[index])
            this.multiChoiceAnswers.selected.splice(selectedPosition, selectedPosition + 1)
        }
        this.$emit('newAnswer', this.multiChoiceAnswers)
    },
    changedAnswer(changedAnswer, index) {
        console.log(changedAnswer)
        //Getting previous selected answer position to replace later
        const selectedPosition = this.multiChoiceAnswers.selected.indexOf(this.multiChoiceAnswers.answers[index])
        //Changing the current value of answer[index] to input value in answers
        this.multiChoiceAnswers.answers.splice(index, index + 1, changedAnswer)
        //Changing the current value of answer[index] to input value in selected
        this.multiChoiceAnswers.selected.splice(selectedPosition, selectedPosition + 1, changedAnswer)

        this.$emit('newAnswer', this.multiChoiceAnswers)

    },
```

Here is the template code:

```
    <v-container>
        <div :key="(answer, index)" v-for="(answer, index) in multiChoiceAnswers.answers">
            <v-layout align-center>
                <v-checkbox hide-details class="shrink mr-2" @click.prevent @change="selectedAnswer($event, index)" :value="answer"></v-checkbox>
                <v-text-field class="checkbox-input" @input="changedAnswer($event, index)" :placeholder="answer"></v-text-field>
                <v-btn @click="removeAnswer(index)">Remove</v-btn>
            </v-layout>
        </div>
    </v-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I must have been to tired or drunk when I posted this ;)

Here is the completely new revised code I did to fix this solution:

```
<template>
<div>
    <v-container>
        <div :key="(answer, index)" v-for="(answer, index) in multiChoiceAnswers.answers">
            <v-layout align-center>
                <v-checkbox hide-details class="shrink mr-2" v-model="answer.selected"></v-checkbox>
                <v-text-field class="checkbox-input" v-model="answer.answerText" :placeholder="answer.answerText"></v-text-field>
                <v-btn @click="removeAnswer(index)">Remove</v-btn>
            </v-layout>
        </div>
    </v-container>
    <v-btn @click="newAnswerOption">Add Answer</v-btn>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['answer'],
        data() {
            return {
                newAnswer: { answerText: 'Your answer here...', selected: false },
                multiChoiceAnswers: {
                    answers: [
                        { answerText: 'test1', selected: false },
                        { answerText: 'test2', selected: false }
                    ],
                },
            }
        },
        created() {
            if (this.answer.answers.length > 1) {
                this.multiChoiceAnswers.answers = this.answer.answers
            } else {
                console.log('Answer Template Generated')
            }
        },
        methods: {
            newAnswerOption() {
                this.multiChoiceAnswers.answers.push(this.newAnswer)
                this.$emit('newAnswer', this.multiChoiceAnswers)
            },
            removeAnswer(index) {
                //Removing the answer
                this.multiChoiceAnswers.answers.splice(index, 1)

                this.$emit('newAnswer', this.multiChoiceAnswers)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What has changed?

I deleted all the previous code that was broken and necessarily complex.

I created a new data array with the objects answers. Each object now has the answerText (string) and the selected (boolean).

The checkbox is now connected to change the answers.selected with v-model

The input is now connected to change the answers.answerText with v-model